# GStreamer Pipeline with udpsrc displaying and saving to file

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm having a hardtime understanding how to build gstreamer pipelines. I've read many questions on Google and on Stack Overflow that are quite similar to mine, but most of them assumes that I know what I'm doing, which is not the case.

I am reading the documentation but reading the documentation and producing a working pipeline seems to be quite different things, and mines are failing.

I'm sending this pipeline with gst-launch-1.0:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc  ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! \
    videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5600
```

And I'm trying to display and record the pipeline from within a C application, using gst_parse_launch, using this pipeline:

```
udpsrc port=5600 ! application/x-rtp, clock-rate=90000,payload=96 \
  ! rtph264depay ! video/x-h264 ! queue ! h264parse !
    tee name=qgc
    qgc. ! queue ! decodebin ! glupload ! glcolorconvert ! qmlglsink name=sink
    qgc. ! queue ! mp4mux ! filesink location=bleh.mp4
```

This pipeline correctly displays video but the resulting file is completely empty in the disk.

0. Is the pipeline written properly? The tee's are a bit strange to reference and I'm not sure if I used them correctly.
1. how can I discover what's wrong within the pipeline? Is there any kind of debugger that I can use to paste a pipeline and have a `pipeline compiler` tell me if things are as they should - or at least if there are obvious flaws in the pipeline I created (like missing caps or incompatible ports)
2. how would I fix this pipeline to receive the video (that plays correctly) and save it in disk? I'm pretty sure is something simple but I haven't figured it out.

The other answers for similar questions are mostly dropping a pipeline that works in the user's computer but in an old version of gstreamer, that does not work today anymore.

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/isomp4/mp4mux.html?gi-language=c#mp4mux-page), mp4mux needs an EOF to finish the file properly, you can force such EOF with `gst-launch-1.0 -e udpsrc port=5600 ! ...`

Here is an example without the tee/qmlsink pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e udpsrc port=5600 ! application/x-rtp, clock-rate=90000,payload=96 \
! rtph264depay ! video/x-h264 ! queue ! h264parse ! queue ! mp4mux ! filesink location=bleh.mp4
```

You can also force the EOF with this code in C:

```
        gst_element_send_event(pipeline, gst_event_new_eos())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HOST=192.168.31.175
```

sender:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink port=5000 host=$HOST
```

receiver(display and record simultaneously):

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 ! "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" \
! rtph264depay ! h264parse \
! tee name=t \
t. ! queue ! mp4mux ! filesink location=xyz.mp4 -e \
t. ! queue leaky=1 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

Notes:

1. `filesink location=xyz.mp4 -e` of `-e` (EOS signal): Pipelines for file saving require a reliable EOS(End of Stream) signal
2. `queue leaky=1` and `sync=false`: make rendering queue not block